# Sahi - get element using custom attributes or multiple attributes

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, sahi

I want to get an element in Sahi script using multiple custom attributes of my choice.
It is a `<td >` having different attributes which are dynamically generated. The title attribute is blank that is `""`. example of the element definition is as follow:

`<td title="" rownumber="1" rmbnum="0,1" rowId="8090.9008.6352.8721" class="my-class my-class2" position="4">`

Here the row id is dynamically generated.
I need to click on this element once this element is clicked then a textbox is generated and we need to fill value in it - value is text format.
I want to use rmbnum and position attributes to get this element.

I have searched the sahi forum but was not able to find it.

regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
_cell({rmbnum:"0,1",position:"4"})
```

The documentation has been updated now. http://sahi.co.in/w/browser-accessor-apis

Answer (score 0):

You can also try use

```
_cell(_table(“items”), rowIndex, columnIndex)
_cell(_table(“items”), rowName, columnName)
```

See http://sahi.co.in/w/_cell for examples.